# How do I disable Firefox Android's popup browser tips?

Tags: firefox-for-android

I'm using Firefox for Android. It keeps showing me popup browser tips at the bottom of the main screens, like bookmarks, top sites, history, etc. I'll close them, but then next time another new one appears. How do I disable these entirely?

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of the aforementioned 'popup browser tips'?

Answer (score 2):

1) Type `about:config` in the address bar and press enter

2) Find the `browser.snippets.enabled` setting and tap to switch the value from `true` to `false`.